# Using Image control in WPF to display System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I assign an in-memory `Bitmap` object to an `Image` control in WPF ?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap but my answer does not leak HBitmap

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Load a WPF BitmapImage from a System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the Source property of the image. Try this code...

```
ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:\\FileName.gif"));

image1.Source = imageSource;
```

Comment: I have Bitmap object, actully it is generated from a scan device, so I cant refer to any location

Answer (score 86):

According to http://khason.net/blog/how-to-use-systemdrawingbitmap-hbitmap-in-wpf/

```
   [DllImport("gdi32")]
   static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

   public static BitmapSource loadBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
   {
       IntPtr ip = source.GetHbitmap();
       BitmapSource bs = null;
       try
       {
           bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ip, 
              IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, 
              System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
       }
       finally
       {
           DeleteObject(ip);
       }

       return bs;
   }
```

It gets System.Drawing.Bitmap (from WindowsBased) and converts it into BitmapSource, which can be actually used as image source for your Image control in WPF.

```
image1.Source = YourUtilClass.loadBitmap(SomeBitmap);
```

Comment: Thx Lars, but I did much simpler, 
BitmapImage bmpi = new BitmapImage();
            bmpi.BeginInit();
            bmpi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ByteArray);
            bmpi.EndInit();
            image1.Source = bmpi;

Comment: Great. You can add your sollution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: I do not see a BitmapImage.StreamSource method.  Prashant, did you type something wrong?

Comment: Or a property, for that matter.

Comment: Patrick, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx

Comment: When using unmanaged handles (e.g. HBITMAP) consider using SafeHandles, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546091/wpf-createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap-memory-leak/7035036#7035036

Comment: @Lars Truijens Very nice, would never of thought of that.

Answer (score 17):

It's easy for disk file, but harder for Bitmap in memory.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp;
Image image;
...
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
ms.Position = 0;
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = ms;
bi.EndInit();

image.Source = bi;
```

[Stealed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap)

Comment: Thx,but the code have not closed the ms.I think you will use http://stackoverflow.com/a/1069509/6116637

Comment: @lindexi Even though `MemoryStream` implements `IDisposable`, it does not require to be disposed explicitly since it does not wrap any unmanaged resource. It is like a byte array and will eventually get collected by GC.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a program with `wpf` and used Database for showing images and this is my code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=HITMAN-PC\MYSQL;
                                      Initial Catalog=Payam;
                                      Integrated Security=True");

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from news", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

string adress = dt.Rows[i]["ImgLink"].ToString();
ImageSource imgsr = new BitmapImage(new Uri(adress));
PnlImg.Source = imgsr;
```

Comment: Good answer, but I would highly recommend wrapping the Sql objects in using statements so they're disposed when you're done using them.