# How Do I Create a System.Windows.Media.ImageSource From a Byte Array?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, arrays, tiff, imagesource

How do I create a System.Windows.Media.ImageSource from a byte array?

I have a byte array, containing the exact and complete file contents of a TIFF image file. I need to display this on the screen, and I have no idea where to even start.

Supposedly, it can be done (according to my boss, our dev team has done it in the past, but nobody remembers how).

Has anyone here ever done something like this before?

Comment: Does ImageSource have a constructor that takes a stream?

Comment: ImageSource is abstract. I'm not sure if any of it's derrived classes do ... The BitmapImage class constructor requires a URI.

Comment: You will get tons of results if you just search in google - http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=WPF+Byte+Array+to+ImageSource&aq=f&oq=&aqi=

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
bi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(ByteArray);
bi.EndInit();
```

Also see [Load a WPF BitmapImage from a System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap) and [Using Image control in WPF to display System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118496/using-image-control-in-wpf-to-display-system-drawing-bitmap)