# How do I set MenuItem's Icon using ItemContainerStyle

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, icons, menuitem

I'm following the example here of binding a `MenuItem` to a data object.

```
<Menu Grid.Row="0" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MenuCommands}">  
    <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Path=DisplayName}"/>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Commands}"/>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}"/>
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{Binding Path=Icon}"/>
        </Style>
    </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>                
</Menu>
```

It all works swimmingly except the `MenuItem`'s icon shows up as the string `System.Drawing.Bitmap`. The bitmap in question is returned by the data object from a compiled resource.

```
internal static System.Drawing.Bitmap folder_page
{
    get
    {
        object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("folder_page", resourceCulture);
        return ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)(obj));
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Good question ... this is a common problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WPF works with `ImageSource`s, not `System.Drawing` classes. You'll need to bind to an `ImageSource`. You could use a converter to convert your `Bitmap` to an `ImageSource`, or you could ditch the resources and do things differently.

Answer (score 9):

Kent (of course) has the right answer. **But I thought I would go ahead and post the code for the converter that converts from the System.Drawing.Bitmap (Windows Forms) to a System.Windows.Windows.Media.BitmapSource (WPF)** ... as this is a common problem/question.

This takes three steps:

1. Use an image converter in your binding.
2. Create the converter.
3. Declare the converter in your resources.

**Here is how you would use an image converter in your binding**:

```
<Setter
    Property="MenuItem.Icon"
    Value="{Binding Path=Icon, Converter={StaticResource imageConverter}}"
/>
```

**And, here is the code for the converter** (put it into a file called ImageConverter.cs) and add it to your project:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Image), typeof(string))]
public class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        BitmapSource bitmapSource;

        IntPtr bitmap = ((Bitmap)value).GetHbitmap();
        try
        {
            bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bitmap, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }
        finally
        {
            DeleteObject(bitmap);
        }

        return bitmapSource;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
    static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);
}
```

**Here is how you declare it in your resources section** (note the local namespace that you will have to add):

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:ImageConverter x:Key="imageConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <!-- some xaml snipped for clarity -->
</Window>
```

And that's it!

---

**Update**

After doing a quick search for similar questions, I noticed that [Lars Truijens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1242/lars-truijens) pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118496/using-image-control-in-wpf-to-display-system-drawing-bitmap/1118557#1118557) that the previous converter implementation leaks. I have updated the converter code above ... so that it doesn't leak.

For more information on the cause of the leak, see the remarks section on this MSDN [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4(v=VS.100).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

WPF's menuitems are somewhat weird in that they **don't** work with [ImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects like the rest of the WPF framework.

The easiest way, that will cause you the least amount of headache is to simply have a property in your viewmodel that returns a full [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control:

```
public Image MenuIcon
{
    get
    {
        return new Image()
               {
                   Source = CreateImageSource("myImage.png")
               };
    }
}
```

And then in your `<Style>` for menu items (which you can set in [ItemContainerStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for example) you simply bind the menu item's `Icon` property to the `MenuIcon` property in your viewmodel:

```
<Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding MenuIcon}" />
```

One could argue that this breaks the spirit of MVVM, but at some point you just have to be pragmatic and move on to more interesting problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I made a ViewModel for a menu item: [AbstractMenuItem](http://svn.soapboxcore.com/svn/trunk/SoapBox/SoapBox.Core/SoapBox.Core.Contracts/Gui/MenuItem/AbstractMenuItem.cs).  Pay particular attention to the Icon region:

```
    #region " Icon "
    /// <summary>
    /// Optional icon that can be displayed in the menu item.
    /// </summary>
    public object Icon
    {
        get
        {
            if (IconFull != null)
            {
                System.Windows.Controls.Image img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
                if (EnableCondition.Condition)
                {
                    img.Source = IconFull;
                }
                else
                {
                    img.Source = IconGray;
                }
                return img;
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
    private BitmapSource IconFull
    {
        get
        {
            return m_IconFull;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_IconFull != value)
            {
                m_IconFull = value;
                if (m_IconFull != null)
                {
                    IconGray = ConvertFullToGray(m_IconFull);
                }
                else
                {
                    IconGray = null;
                }
                NotifyPropertyChanged(m_IconArgs);
            }
        }
    }
    private BitmapSource m_IconFull = null;
    static readonly PropertyChangedEventArgs m_IconArgs =
        NotifyPropertyChangedHelper.CreateArgs<AbstractMenuItem>(o => o.Icon);

    private BitmapSource IconGray { get; set; }

    private BitmapSource ConvertFullToGray(BitmapSource full)
    {
        FormatConvertedBitmap gray = new FormatConvertedBitmap();

        gray.BeginInit();
        gray.Source = full;
        gray.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Gray32Float;
        gray.EndInit();

        return gray;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is a helper function so you can assign the Icon directly
    /// from a Bitmap, such as one from a resources file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    protected void SetIconFromBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap value)
    {
        BitmapSource b = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            value.GetHbitmap(),
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        IconFull = b;
    }

    #endregion
```

You just derive from this class and in the constructor you call SetIconFromBitmap and pass in a picture from your resx file.

Here's how I bound to those IMenuItems in the [Workbench Window](http://svn.soapboxcore.com/svn/trunk/SoapBox/SoapBox.Core/SoapBox.Core.Workbench/Workbench/WorkBenchView.xaml):

```
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(local:Workbench.MainMenu)}">
        <Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{Binding Path=(contracts:IMenuItem.Header)}"/>
                <Setter Property="MenuItem.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=(contracts:IMenuItem.Items)}"/>
                <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{Binding Path=(contracts:IMenuItem.Icon)}"/>
                <Setter Property="MenuItem.IsCheckable" Value="{Binding Path=(contracts:IMenuItem.IsCheckable)}"/>
                <Setter Property="MenuItem.IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=(contracts:IMenuItem.IsChecked)}"/>
                <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding}"/>
                <Setter Property="MenuItem.Visibility" Value="{Binding Path=(contracts:IControl.Visible), 
                    Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                <Setter Property="MenuItem.ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=(contracts:IControl.ToolTip)}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=(contracts:IMenuItem.IsSeparator)}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                                    <Separator Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static MenuItem.SeparatorStyleKey}}"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
    </Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity: I've come up with this:

```
<Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding IconUrl, Converter={ns:UrlToImageConverter Width=16, Height=16}}"/>
    </Style>
</Menu.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The converter is a combination of `MarkupExtension` and a `IValueConverter`, so you can specify it inline without having to make it a static resource.

It uses the `System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter` to convert an uri to an `ImageSource` and then creates an `Image` control with that source.
As bonus it uses the `serviceProvider` parameter as supplied to `ProvideValue` so it can resolve relative image urls as WPF would do it.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(Image))]
[ValueConversion(typeof(Uri), typeof(Image))]
public class UrlToImageConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    public int? MaxWidth { get; set; }

    public int? MaxHeight { get; set; }

    public int? MinWidth { get; set; }

    public int? MinHeight { get; set; }

    public Stretch? Stretch { get; set; }

    public StretchDirection? StretchDirection { get; set; }

    private static readonly ImageSourceConverter _converter = new System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter();

    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public UrlToImageConverter()
    {
        _serviceProvider = new ServiceContainer();
    }

    /// <summary>  </summary>
    private UrlToImageConverter(UrlToImageConverter provider, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider ?? new ServiceContainer();
        MaxWidth = provider.MaxWidth;
        MaxHeight = provider.MaxHeight;
        MinWidth = provider.MinWidth;
        MinHeight = provider.MinHeight;
        Stretch = provider.Stretch;
        StretchDirection = provider.StretchDirection;
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;

        var context = GetTypeDescriptorContext();

        bool canConvert;
        if (context == null)
            canConvert = _converter.CanConvertFrom(value.GetType());
        else
            canConvert = _converter.CanConvertFrom(context, value.GetType());

        if (canConvert)
        {
            if (context == null)
                value = _converter.ConvertFrom(value);
            else
                value = _converter.ConvertFrom(context, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, value);

            if (value is ImageSource source)
            {
                var img = new Image { Source = source };
                if (MaxWidth != null) img.MaxWidth = MaxWidth.Value;
                if (MaxHeight != null) img.MaxHeight = MaxHeight.Value;
                if (MinWidth != null) img.MinWidth = MinWidth.Value;
                if (MinHeight != null) img.MinHeight = MinHeight.Value;                    
                img.Stretch = Stretch ?? System.Windows.Media.Stretch.Uniform;
                img.StretchDirection = StretchDirection ?? System.Windows.Controls.StretchDirection.Both;
                return img;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private ITypeDescriptorContext GetTypeDescriptorContext()
    {
        if (_serviceProvider is ITypeDescriptorContext context)
            return context;
        else
            return (ITypeDescriptorContext)_serviceProvider?.GetService(typeof(ITypeDescriptorContext));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return new UrlToImageConverter(this, serviceProvider);
    }
}
```