# Get BitmapSource From Image Control

Tags: c#

why the following code is returning null for btmSrc ?

```
DrawingImage drawingElement =(DrawingImage)System.Windows.Application.Current.TryFindResource(name);
 System.Windows.Controls.Image image = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
 image.Source = drawingElement as ImageSource;

BitmapSource btmSrc = image.Source as BitmapSource;
```

Comment: We'll need to see much more code than just this. What is "image" and where is it defined?

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying your code :

```
DrawingImage drawingElement = (DrawingImage)System.Windows.Application.Current.TryFindResource(name);
BitmapSource btmSrc = drawingElement as BitmapSource;
```

As [`DrawingImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingimage.aspx) doesn't inherit from BitmapSource, the result will be null.

---

I don't have a `DrawingImage` to test (so take this as a pseudocode not as a copy-paste solution) but the conversion code should look something like this :

```
// Create a visual from a drawing
DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
drawingVisual.Drawing.Children.Add(drawingImage.Drawing);

// Render it to a WPF bitmap
var renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
    drawingVisual.Drawing.Bounds.Right,
    drawingVisual.Drawing.Bounds.Bottom, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
renderTargetBitmap.Render(drawingVisual);

// Create a bitmap with the correct size
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
    renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,  PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size),
    ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
renderTargetBitmap.CopyPixels(Int32Rect.Empty, data.Scan0,
    data.Height * data.Stride, data.Stride);
bmp.UnlockBits(data);
```

The last part being taken from [Is there a good way to convert between BitmapSource and Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284353/is-there-a-good-way-to-convert-between-bitmapsource-and-bitmap)

Comment: you are right! what i was trying to do it do create a system.drawing.Bitmap from the drawingElement. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Are you sure that drawingElement is not null, i'll expect a BitmapImage instead of a DrawingImage there (and in this case multiple conversions to the System.Drawing types exists) but that would imply the the resource lookup failed because otherwise the cast would have thrown.

Comment: No drawingElement is not null. it is retrieving the DrawingImage that is saved in a xaml file. Please provide me with links or idea to convert DrawingImage to System.Drawing.