# Get file Thumbnail image with transparency

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, bitmapimage, bitmapsource

I want to get file's thumbnail with transparency.
I have the following code to achieve it:

```
BitmapImage GetThumbnail(string filePath)
{
    ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(filePath);
    BitmapSource shellThumb = shellFile.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmapSource;

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(shellThumb.PixelWidth, shellThumb.PixelHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    BitmapData data = bmp.LockBits(new System.Drawing.Rectangle(System.Drawing.Point.Empty, bmp.Size), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
    shellThumb.CopyPixels(Int32Rect.Empty, data.Scan0, data.Height * data.Stride, data.Stride);
    bmp.UnlockBits(data);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
    ms.Position = 0;
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.StreamSource = ms;
    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
    bi.EndInit();

    return bi;
}
```

I mixed the codes from here:
[Is there a good way to convert between BitmapSource and Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284353/is-there-a-good-way-to-convert-between-bitmapsource-and-bitmap)
and
[Load a WPF BitmapImage from a System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap)

With this way, I convert `BitmapSource` to Bitmap, then I covert the Bitmap to `BitmapImage`.
I am pretty sure there's a way to covert `BitmapSource` directly to `BitmapImage` **while saving the transparency**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to encode the `BitmapSource` to a `BitmapImage`, you can choose any encoder you want in this example I use `PngBitmapEncoder`

Example:

```
private BitmapImage GetThumbnail(string filePath)
{
    ShellFile shellFile = ShellFile.FromFilePath(filePath);
    BitmapSource shellThumb = shellFile.Thumbnail.ExtraLargeBitmapSource;

    BitmapImage bImg = new BitmapImage();
    PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();

    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(shellThumb));
    encoder.Save(memoryStream);
    bImg.BeginInit();
    bImg.StreamSource = memoryStream;
    bImg.EndInit();
    return bImg;
}
```

Comment: It works, but it works only when I remove the "using" from the memoryStream, any idea why?

Comment: oh, my bad, its because the using disposes the stream, I did not test that code :(, I'll update

Answer (score -1):

Did you try: `System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`  (**without** the P between Format32-P-Argb)

MSDN:

`Format32bppArgb`   -> Specifies that the format is 32 bits per pixel; 8 bits each are used for the alpha, red, green, and blue components.

`Format32bppPArgb` -> Specifies that the format is 32 bits per pixel; 8 bits each are used for the alpha, red, green, and blue components. **The red, green, and blue components are premultiplied**, according to the alpha component.

Comment: Works the same, but how does it relate to my question? My function does give me the Thumbnail with transparency but I do it in two steps (as I said), I am pretty sure I can do it in one step