# Is it possible to convert a byte[] to a bitmapsource?

Tags: c#, bitmap, arrays, bitmapsource

So far I have:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData))
{
     Bitmap img = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

And then I would imagine I would be able to get a BitmapSource from img somehow? If this is totally wrong please feel free to correct me.

Comment: Perhaps with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284353/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the easiest solution:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData))
{
    BitmapDecoder bitmapDecoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(ms, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
    BitmapSource photo = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapDecoder.Frames.Single());
}
```

Haven't tested it yet but my code was taken from: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104929/Bitmap-to-BitmapSource)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [BitmapSource.Create()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms616045(v=vs.110).aspx). But you need to create pallete first:

```
var colors = new List<Color>();
colors.Add(Colors.Red);
colors.Add(Colors.Blue);
colors.Add(Colors.Green);
var palette = new BitmapPalette(colors);
```