# How to convert Bitmap SharpDX

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx

How to convert `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource` to `Bitmap` for SharpDX?

Comment: That awkward moment when people link an answer that explains how to convert from bitmapSource to system.drawing.bitmap when the question is how to convert to SharpDX.bitmap which aren't the same because actual sharpDX.bitmap doesn't have the same pixel pattern and requires much more config than GDI bitmap.... +1 for trolling answers

Comment: wrongly closed -- not the same question at all.

Answer (score 0):

BitmapSource Class Represents a single, constant set of pixels at a certain size and resolution. For converting BitmapSource to Bitmap you can see this link [Is there a good way to convert between BitmapSource and Bitmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284353/is-there-a-good-way-to-convert-between-bitmapsource-and-bitmap)

Comment: Not just bitmap. Bitmap for SharpDX

Comment: Well in that case you can see SharpDX.WIC.Bitmap class and SharpDX.WIC.BitmapSource class for converting to bitmap

Comment: Next question.
How to convert System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource to SharpDX.WIC.BitmapSource

Comment: Poor jshapen, people really of no clue of what they are answering LOL, they don't understand sharpDX doesn't work the same way as GDI...