# Show Drawing.Image in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I´ve got an instance of System.Drawing.Image.

How can I show this in my WPF-application?

I tried with `img.Source` but that does not work.

Comment: Possibly Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118496/using-image-control-in-wpf-to-display-system-drawing-bitmap

Comment: Possible duplicate of [wpf - Can i use System.Drawing in wpf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663056/wpf-can-i-use-system-drawing-in-wpf)

Answer (score 26):

I have the same problem and solve it by combining several answers.

```
System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp;
Image image;
...
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    ms.Position = 0;

    var bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bi.StreamSource = ms;
    bi.EndInit();
}

image.Source = bi;
//bmp.Dispose(); //if bmp is not used further. Thanks @Peter
```

From [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap)

Comment: Don't forget to dispose `bmp`.

Comment: what is **bmp** used for in this example?

Comment: @juagicre Any properly formed System.Drawing.Bitmap you want to display in System.Drawing.Image of WPF window.

Comment: bmp Bitmap should be initialized, no? Well I guess this is done in the "..." part of the code :)

Comment: @juagicre Yes, it should. In the "...", exactly, or it should come from outside of the function etc.

Comment: @juagicre bmp is the input System.Drawing.Image that needs to be converted.

Answer (score 21):

To load an Image into a WPF Image control you will need a System.Windows.Media.ImageSource.

You need to convert your Drawing.Image object to an ImageSource object :

```
 public static BitmapSource GetImageStream(Image myImage)
    {
        var bitmap = new Bitmap(myImage);
        IntPtr bmpPt = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
        BitmapSource bitmapSource =
         System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
               bmpPt,
               IntPtr.Zero,
               Int32Rect.Empty,
               BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        //freeze bitmapSource and clear memory to avoid memory leaks
        bitmapSource.Freeze();
        DeleteObject(bmpPt);

        return bitmapSource;
    }
```

Declaration of the DeleteObject method.

```
[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
internal static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr value);
```

Answer (score 14):

If you use a converter, you can actually bind to the `Image` object. You will just need to create an `IValueConverter` that will convert the `Image` to a `BitmapSource`.

I used AlexDrenea's sample code inside the converter to do the real work.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Image), typeof(BitmapSource))]
public class ImageToBitmapSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr value);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is null || !(value is Image myImage))
        {//ensure provided value is valid image.
            return null;
        }

        if (myImage.Height > Int16.MaxValue || myImage.Width > Int16.MaxValue)
        {//GetHbitmap will fail if either dimension is larger than max short value.
            //Throwing here to reduce cpu and resource usage when error can be detected early.
            throw new ArgumentException($"Cannot convert System.Drawing.Image with either dimension greater than {Int16.MaxValue} to BitmapImage.\nProvided image's dimensions: {myImage.Width}x{myImage.Height}", nameof(value));
        }

        using Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(myImage); //ensure Bitmap is disposed of after usefulness is fulfilled.
        IntPtr bmpPt = bitmap.GetHbitmap();
        try
        {
            BitmapSource bitmapSource =
             System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
                   bmpPt,
                   IntPtr.Zero,
                   Int32Rect.Empty,
                   BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            //freeze bitmapSource and clear memory to avoid memory leaks
            bitmapSource.Freeze();
            return bitmapSource;
        }
        finally
        { //done in a finally block to ensure this memory is not leaked regardless of exceptions.
            DeleteObject(bmpPt);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In your XAML you will need to add the converter.

```
<utils:ImageToBitmapSourceConverter x:Key="ImageConverter"/>

<Image Source="{Binding ThumbSmall, Converter={StaticResource ImageConverter}}"
                   Stretch="None"/>
```

Comment: Self-contained. I like it