# how to assign System.Drawing.Image object in WPF's Image control

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am using a DLL which is returning a `System.Drawing.Image` object in return. I was using that DLL in winform c# and was working fine. Now am upgrading my applicationin in WPF and confuse how can i assign this return object `(System.Drawing.Image)` to my `Image` control in wpf ? Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
// Winforms Image we want to get the WPF Image from...

System.Drawing.Image imgWinForms = WindowsImageFromDLL();

// ImageSource ...

BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

bi.BeginInit();

MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

// Save to a memory stream...

imgWinForms.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Bmp);

// Rewind the stream...

ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

// Tell the WPF image to use this stream...

bi.StreamSource = ms;

bi.EndInit();
```

This way you image will not be stored as file in system.

Comment: System.Drawing.Image is not  avaiable in WPF

Comment: @UzmaGelani: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10663056/wpf-can-i-use-system-drawing-in-wpf