# ImageBox insert image without path

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I would like to add the image directly to the image box, so `imgVarschaubild.Source = sa;`

Unfortunately this does not work, how do I do it? Without which I have to save the picture first but must directly insert the picture?

My solution at the moment:

```
System.Drawing.Image sa;


    ....


if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
  sa.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName);
  MessageBox.Show(saveFileDialog.FileName);
  ImageSource imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(saveFileDialog.FileName));

  imgVorschaubild.Source = imageSource;
}
```

Comment: System.Drawing.Image is a Windows Form class. What image do you want to display? Is it an image file or what?

Comment: The image was made by an OxyPlot, so I have the image only as a variable and would like to add it directly to the image box. I do not want to save it before. (I have created the image in a method and this method returns me the image.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Drawing.Image` is a Windows Form class. You could try to convert it to a `BitmapSource` using any of the suggestions and code samples from here:

[Show Drawing.Image in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077498/show-drawing-image-in-wpf)

Once you have done that you could set the `Source` property of the `Image` element to the `BitmapSource`:

```
imgVorschaubild.Source = GetImageStream(sa);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I tried different things, but without success. Would you give me a clue?

Comment: "different things"? Did you try the GetImageStream as I suggested? What happened?

Comment: When I use `GetImageStream` comes as a message _The name does not exist in the current context_.

Comment: You need to copy the GetImageStream method from the link I gave you into your code...It is not a built-in method.

Comment: Sorry Sir, Thank you for your sincere effort.

Answer (score 0):

It seem's like you are not using the MVVM pattern. I hardly recommend it.
If you use it you could easily bind your imagePath to an Image.

You just need a string property in your ViewModel and bind to it in your View like

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
```