# C# : Get Source of Image from Memory over Bitmap and BitmapImage

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, memorystream, bitmapimage

-I am trying to write a method for a Card Scanner and I am quite new in `C#` :)

-The application I wrote can scan and gets the images from the Scanner, but I can not show them on the `WPF`.

-The `SDK` is written for `Windows Forms`, so I have to do a conversion from `Bitmap` to `BitmapImage` (What I actually did).

-When I try to add a Source with `XAML`, it works, but it should get the Source from the Memory! But I have no Idea how it supposed to be on `C#`

Please help! I´ve tried almost everything. Thank you

```
class StartScan
{
    protected internal SDKWrapper sdk = new SDKWrapper();
    MainWindow mw;

    public void Scan()
    {
        try
        {
            ShowImage(sdk.ScanAndGetImage(), false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {           
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void ShowImage(System.Drawing.Image image, bool converted)
    {
        mw = new MainWindow();

        if (image == null)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("IMAGE=NULL");
            return;
        }
        int displayW =(int) mw.CardBoxRect.Width;
        int displayH = (int) mw.CardBoxRect.Height;

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(displayW,displayH);

        mw.CardBox.Source = BitmapToImageSource(b);
    }

    BitmapImage BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine(bitmap.ToString());
            bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            memory.Position = 0;
            BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();

            bitmapimage.BeginInit();
            bitmapimage.StreamSource = memory;

            bitmapimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapimage.EndInit();
            bitmapimage.Freeze();
            return bitmapimage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you Tried BitmapFrame, which you can obtain from reading a memory stream with a BitmapDecoder ?

Comment: Your scanned image is stored in `image` that is passed in to `ShowImage`. You then create a new Bitmap object and convert it to a BitmapImage, both of these will be empty since you didn't reference the image when creating them. You should create a Bitmap from the Image. [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10077498/show-drawing-image-in-wpf) for answers on how to do this.

Comment: @MikeT FYI You can also create a BitmapImage from a stream, by setting its `StreamSource`  property.

Comment: Besides what Lithium has said, you are also creating a new MainWindow in ShowImage, which makes no sense.

Comment: @Clemens i know you can, but you can get odd behaviour when the stream is disposed before the image is loaded, when using the decoder and frame directly i find you get much more predicable results

Comment: For what Lithium has pointed out, you may try to simply cast `image` to `Bitmap`, like `var b = (Bitmap)image;`

Comment: @MikeT Both BitmapFrame and BitmapImage behave identically with respect to the `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` option, which ensures that the BitmapSource is loaded before its source stream is closed.

Comment: @Lithium Thank you for your comment. i already red that post and tried what you wrote, but there were no changes.

Comment: @A.Cinar I'm pretty sure your problem then relies in what Clemens said. You are creating a new MainWindow in the ShowImage method, but that window is never shown (unless you are calling show in the constructor). Have you tried debugging at all? Set a breakpoint and check that each object is loading correctly (Image, Bitmap, BitmapImage).

Comment: You were right, the Problem was in the MainWindow.Thank you soo much!

Comment: But I have another issue now, it shows the scanned image, but I am getting just a black image, nothing else, do you have any suggestions?