# Bitmap class in WPF

Tags: wpf, bitmap, kinect, emgucv

I'm working with Emgu Cv in Winforms to do face recognition using Kinect. Now, i want to move to WPF. However, the EmguCv library support only **Bitmap** class.

Can i use the Bitmap class (used in Winforms) in WPF ? if not, is there an other method to use Emgu cv with kinect in WPF?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

[`System.Drawing.Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) can not be used directly as image source for WPF, so you have to convert it to [`System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx).

The best way to do it is by using [`Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhbitmap.aspx).

You can use an extension method:

```
[DllImport("gdi32")]
private static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(this System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
    }

    IntPtr ip = source.GetHbitmap();
    try
    {
        return System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ip,
            IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty,
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
    finally
    {
        DeleteObject(ip);
    }
}
```

Please note that you must invoke `DeleteObject`, because `Bitmap.GetHbitmap()` leaks a GDI handle (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1118557/63011) answer).

Once you have a `BitmapSource`, you can display it using an [`Image`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) control and by setting the [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx) property.

You can read more about WPF imaging in this article: [Imaging Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873.aspx)

Comment: Hello, should i add a reference to system.Drawing ?

Comment: @RafikHaceb Yes, make sure that your project has a reference to `System.Drawing.dll` and `PresentationCore.dll`.
By the way, if you find an answer helpful, you can mark it as 'accepted'. See [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/164263).