# What is the equivalent function for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap

I have the following function that works in Windows Form but I will need help to make it work in WPF with the image control.

```
public static Bitmap CreateBitmap(byte[] bytes, int width, int height)
{
        var rgbBytes = new byte[bytes.Length * 3];
        for (var i = 0; i <= bytes.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            rgbBytes[(i * 3)] = bytes[i];
            rgbBytes[(i * 3) + 1] = bytes[i];
            rgbBytes[(i * 3) + 2] = bytes[i];
        }
        var bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        var data = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        for (var i = 0; i <= bmp.Height - 1; i++)
        {
            var p = new IntPtr(data.Scan0.ToInt32() + data.Stride * i);
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(rgbBytes, i * bmp.Width * 3, p, bmp.Width * 3);
        }

        bmp.UnlockBits(data);

        return bmp;
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: So what exactly is not working?

Comment: Consider using [WriteableBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb is not recognised in WPF

Comment: Are you referencing the System.Drawing dll?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
BitmapSource bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
      bmp.GetHbitmap(),
      IntPtr.Zero,
      System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
      BitmapSizeOptions.FromWidthAndHeight(bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
image.Source = bs;
```

`image` is an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.aspx) control.

Also, please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368626/bitmap-class-in-wpf) as it mentions some important facts about `bmp.GetHbitmap()` leaking a handle.

Finally, this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/104929/Bitmap-to-BitmapSource) might be of help.