# Load DDS file from stream and display in WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.5, dds-format

I am trying to load a DirectDraw Surface (DDS) file and display it in a WPF application.
This is how I get the stream from a zip archive:

```
using (ZipArchive clientArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(levelsPath + mapName + @"\client.zip"))
{
    var entry = clientArchive.GetEntry("hud/minimap/ingamemap.dds");
    var stream = entry.Open();
}
```

Now, how do I display the DDS image (just the first, highest quality mipmap) in my WPF application?

Answer (score 2):

I recently used DDSImage class from [kprojects](https://code.google.com/p/kprojects/downloads/list). It can load DXT1 and DXT5 compressend DDS files.

Simply create a new instance with a byte array and access all mipmaps through the property `images` of type `Bitmap[]`:

```
DDSImage img = new DDSImage(File.ReadAllBytes(@"e:\myfile.dds"));

for (int i = 0; i < img.images.Length; i++)
{
    img.images[i].Save(@"e:\mipmap-" + i + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

Im you got your mipmap as Bitmap you could display it with an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)-Control. To create an BitmapSource, based on the Bitmap in memory [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1118557) pointed me the right way.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (ZipArchive clientArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(levelsPath + mapName + @"\client.zip"))
{
    var entry = clientArchive.GetEntry("hud/minimap/ingamemap.dds");
    var stream = entry.Open();
    ImageObject.Source = DDSConverter.Convert(stream,null,null,null);
}
```

Taken from [here.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ryantrem/archive/2010/06/06/loading-dds-files-as-wpf-imagesources-using-xna.aspx)

```
public class DDSConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly DDSConverter defaultInstace = new DDSConverter();

    public static DDSConverter Default
    {
        get
        {
            return DDSConverter.defaultInstace;
        }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
        }
        else if (value is Stream)
        {
            return DDSConverter.Convert((Stream)value);
        }
        else if (value is string)
        {
            return DDSConverter.Convert((string)value);
        }
        else if (value is byte[])
        {
            return DDSConverter.Convert((byte[])value);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0} cannot convert from {1}.", this.GetType().FullName, value.GetType().FullName));
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("{0} does not support converting back.", this.GetType().FullName));
    }

    public static ImageSource Convert(string filePath)
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            return DDSConverter.Convert(fileStream);
        }
    }

    public static ImageSource Convert(byte[] imageData)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageData))
        {
            return DDSConverter.Convert(memoryStream);
        }
    }

    public static ImageSource Convert(Stream stream)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Following is a simple usage example:

```
<Image x:Name="ImageObject" Source="{Binding Source=Test.dds, Converter={x:Static local:DDSConverter.Default}}" />
```

Comment: This solution requires me to install XNA 3.1 (4.0 won't work since some of the methods/classes are not there anymore) which in turn requires me to install Visual C# Studio Express Edition 2008 (which I don't want since I have VS2013). This does not solve my problem.