# Generating a QR code image in a C#/WPF program

Tags: c#, wpf, qr-code

I am working on a project where I want to be able to display a QR Code on the screen to the user.

I'm using the QR Code generate from http://qrcodenet.codeplex.com/ which is working fine but I've only found a way to write the QR Code to a file which is now what I want.

Instead, I want the image to be displayed in a control on the WPF window but I don't want to create the file and then set the source of the image to an image control of the newly created file. This seems like a bit of overkill so I'm hoping there is way I can put the stream straight into an image control instead of into a file.

Below is the code that I have so far.

```
private void generateQRCode()
        {
            QrEncoder encoder = new QrEncoder(ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);
            QrCode qrCode;
            encoder.TryEncode("Test", out qrCode);

            DrawingBrushRenderer dRenderer = new DrawingBrushRenderer(
                new FixedModuleSize(2, QuietZoneModules.Two), System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black, 
                    System.Windows.Media.Brushes.White);

            DrawingBrush dBrush = dRenderer.DrawBrush(qrCode.Matrix);
            System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle rect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
            rect.Width = 150;
            rect.Height = 150;
            rect.Fill = dBrush;

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            dRenderer.WriteToStream(qrCode.Matrix, ImageFormatEnum.PNG, ms, new System.Windows.Point(96, 96));

            var image = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms), new System.Drawing.Size(new System.Drawing.Point(200, 200)));

            image.Save("myImage.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
               
        }
```

Basically, I want to replace the `image.save()` function so that the image is instead show directly in a control on my apps GUI, not written to a separate file.

Comment: Not sure about WPF, but I know in WinForms, there is a PictureBox control where you can just set the .Image property of the picture box to your raw image bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've actually never written anything in WPF, so this could be wrong, but you probably want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap). I'll copy the answer from that question below:

```
using(MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
{
    image.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
    memory.Position = 0;
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
}
```

Then, I assume, you can associate that BitmapImage with whatever control you use to display the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer to this here: [Using Image control in WPF to display System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1118496/using-image-control-in-wpf-to-display-system-drawing-bitmap)

HBipmaps from System.Drawing can not be used directly in WPF. [Lars Truijens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1242/lars-truijens) on his post goes to explain but see the snipped of the post below:

According to http://khason.net/blog/how-to-use-systemdrawingbitmap-hbitmap-in-wpf/

```
   [DllImport("gdi32")]
   static extern int DeleteObject(IntPtr o);

   public static BitmapSource loadBitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap source)
   {
       IntPtr ip = source.GetHbitmap();
       BitmapSource bs = null;
       try
       {
           bs = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(ip, 
              IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, 
              System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
       }
       finally
       {
           DeleteObject(ip);
       }

       return bs;
   }
```

It gets System.Drawing.Bitmap (from WindowsBased) and converts it into BitmapSource, which can be actually used as image source for your Image control in WPF.

```
image1.Source = YourUtilClass.loadBitmap(SomeBitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

With package QrCode.Net (Install-Package QrCode.Net) we can generate the matrix data of qrcode content, so I have make a WPF control with the matrix data.

QRCode.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp1.QRCode"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="HorizontalPanel">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PointTemplate">
        <Rectangle Fill="{Binding Color}" Width="{Binding Size, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" Height="{Binding Size, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="LineTemplate">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource HorizontalPanel}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PointTemplate}">
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Name="qrcodeControl" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LineTemplate}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel></StackPanel>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

QRCode.xaml.cs

```
using Gma.QrCodeNet.Encoding;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for QRCode.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class QRCode : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public QRCode()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //default point size
            this.Size = 3;
            qrcodeControl.ItemsSource = QRMatrix;
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<QrCodePoint>> qrMatrix = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<QrCodePoint>>();
        ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<QrCodePoint>> QRMatrix
        {
            get
            {
                return this.qrMatrix;
            }
        }

        public new static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Content",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(QRCode),
            new UIPropertyMetadata((s, e) =>
            {
                QRCode dp = s as QRCode;
                dp.QRMatrix.Clear();
                dp.Generate(e.NewValue.ToString()).ForEach(
                    line =>
                    {
                        ObservableCollection<QrCodePoint> linePoints = new ObservableCollection<QrCodePoint>();
                        dp.qrMatrix.Add(linePoints);
                        foreach (var point in line)
                        {
                            linePoints.Add(point);
                        }
                    });
                dp.RaisePropertyChanged("Content");
            }));

        public new string Content
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(ContentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Size",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(QRCode),
            new UIPropertyMetadata((s, e) =>
            {
                QRCode dp = s as QRCode;
                dp.RaisePropertyChanged("Size");
            }));

        public double Size
        {
            get { return (double)GetValue(SizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(SizeProperty, value); }
        }

        public List<QrCodePoint[]> Generate(string content)
        {
            List<QrCodePoint[]> result = new List<QrCodePoint[]>();
            QrEncoder encoder = new QrEncoder(ErrorCorrectionLevel.M);
            QrCode qrCode;
            encoder.TryEncode(content, out qrCode);

            for (int i = 0; i < qrCode.Matrix.Height; i++)
            {
                var line = new QrCodePoint[qrCode.Matrix.Width];
                result.Add(line);
                for (int j = 0; j < qrCode.Matrix.Width; j++)
                {
                    line[j] = new QrCodePoint() { Color = qrCode.Matrix[i, j] ? Brushes.Black : Brushes.White };
                }
            }

            return result;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }

    public class QrCodePoint
    {
        public SolidColorBrush Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and the MainWindow to use this WPF control

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <local:QRCode Grid.Column="1" Size="5" Content="Hello, world!"></local:QRCode>
</Grid>
```