# Converting Image to bitmap turns background black

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I need to convert an Image to a bitmap.

initially a gif was read in as bytes and then converted to an Image.

But when I try convert the image to a bit map, the graphic displaying in my picturebox has a black background when it used to be white.

Here is the code:

```
    var image = (System.Drawing.Image)value;
        // Winforms Image we want to get the WPF Image from...
        var bitmap = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        bitmap.BeginInit();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        // Save to a memory stream...
        image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        // Rewind the stream...
        memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        bitmap.StreamSource = memoryStream;
        bitmap.EndInit();
        return bitmap;
```

Can some one explain why the background is going black and how i can stop it doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Don't save as a bitmap file. The file format doesn't support transparency, so the image will be saved without transparency.

You can use the PNG file format instead. That will preserve the transparency.

If you really need it to use the bitmap file format, you have to make it non-transparent first. Create a new bitmap with the same size, use the `Graphics.FromImage` method to get a graphics object to draw on the image, use the `Clear` method to fill it with the background color that you want, use the `DrawImage` method to draw your image on top of the background, and then save that bitmap.

Comment: Worked well for me too. Theres a bit of code showing this solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6513633/convert-transparent-png-to-jpg-with-non-black-background-color

Comment: But BMP does support transparency does it not?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and Bitmap file format. You can save a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` with transparency layer because it fully supports it.

```
var image = (System.Drawing.Image)value;
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image); //Make a Bitmap from the image
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png); //Format it as PNG so the transparency layer remains.
//Rest of the code...
```

A `bmp` file format can also support transparency in particular ways. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29585717/5786039).