# How to save graphics into png or jpg file c#

Tags: c#, graphics, png, drawing, jpeg

I'm working on a graphic application in C# windows form app. I have a form that I can draw on it.
so I created a [Graphic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) object from the form.

```
void StartPoint()
{
    Graphics graphic;
    graphic = PaintWindow.CreateGraphics();
}
```

I want to know how can I export this graphic as a png or jpg file after drawing something.
before this, I searched for this question but I didn't find any useful.
some people resolve this with printing that part of the screen:

```
graphic.CopyFromScreen(...);
```

this way is not useful for me because some times I need to transparent my background image.
also, I tried Bitmap way :

```
    private void ExportBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(PaintWindow.Width, PaintWindow.Height, graphic);
        b.Save(...);
    }
```

but when I save, the image file is completely black.
this is my application:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried saving the bitmap with `PNG` format like this : `b.Save(fileName, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)` ? Or you can check the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8317271/8949476)

Comment: Do you get all black if you draw with any other color than black? (This test will tell us if it is an alpha-channel related problem.)

Comment: yes , I did png  format. I saw that answer before.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to draw to an image you want to [create your graphics from that image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1):

```
using(var myGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap))
{ 
    // Do drawing 
}
```

You can then proceed to to use CopyFromScreen and other drawing methods to update the image and then save it.