# Prism v4, MEF, WPF - Using proper Uri for module graphic

Tags: wpf, prism, uri, mef, pack-uri

My solution's structure is:

[image]

CI.Frontier.Classic contains a MEF module. My application uses the RibbonWindow control, and the modules define what menu items should be created. I can successfully add a button to the ribbon control from the CI.Frontier.Classic module, however, I cannot figure out the proper Uri to ClassicFrontierToopTip.png

Heres the code in FrontierClassic.cs that creates the tab, button and attempting to set the ribbon ToolTipImage

```
public void CreateMenuItems()
{
    TabData tabData = new TabData("Legacy");

    GroupData groupData = new GroupData("Internal");
    tabData.GroupDataCollection.Add(groupData);

    ButtonData classicFrontierBtn = new ButtonData()
    {
        Label = "Classic Frontier",
        ToolTipTitle = "Classic Frontier",
        ToolTipDescription = "Open Classic Frontier",
        ToolTipImage = new Uri("./Graphics/ClassicFrontierToolTip.png", UriKind.Relative)
    };
    classicFrontierBtn.Command.RegisterCommand(new DelegateCommand(LoadFrontierView));


    groupData.ControlDataCollection.Add(classicFrontierBtn);

    _ribbonService.AddTab(tabData);
}
```

This Uri doesn't work as the tooltip does not display. Can I use the UriKind.Relative or should I be using some sort of "pack uri"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The robust approach would be to leverage the [pack syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069%28VS.85%29.aspx)...

```
new Uri("pack://application:,,,/CI.Frontier.Classic;component/Graphics/ClassicFrontierToolTip.png", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Include an icon for a Prism module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628767/include-an-icon-for-a-prism-module)  solved it...

```
ToolTipImage = new Uri("/" + GetType().Assembly.ToString().Split(',')[0] + ";component/Graphics/ClassicFrontierToolTip.png", UriKind.Relative)
```

Not sure if this is the best solution though.