# How to reference icons inside .resx files from xaml?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, icons

I am working on a C# WPF application, using .resx files for resource management. Now, I'm trying to add icons (.ico) to the project but I'm running into some problems.

```xml
<Image Name="imgMin" Grid.Column="0"
       Stretch="UniformToFill"
       Cursor="Hand" 
       MouseDown="imgMin_MouseDown">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="\Images\minimize_glow.ico"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="\Images\minimize_glow.ico"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

This works fine, but when I move the icon into AppResources.resx I run into problems with referencing it in the xaml code. What should I be using instead of the Setter Property=... lines above? This:

```xml
<Setter Property="Source" Value="{x:Static res:AppResources.minimize}"/>
```

doesn't work, I think I probably need to use a different Property than "Source" because Value isn't a string pointing to the icon but the icon itself now. I can't figure out which one to use though - some help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Source` property does not "want" a string, it just converts it when it gets one. If you add an icon to the resources it will be of the type `System.Drawing.Icon`. You will need to convert it to an `ImageSource` via converter.

You can do a static access to resources but it needs to comply with the expected syntax of [`x:Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx).

e.g.

```
xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:Test.Properties"
```

```xml
<Image MaxHeight="100" MaxWidth="100">
    <Image.Source>
        <Binding Source="{x:Static prop:Resources.icon}">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <vc:IconToImageSourceConverter/>
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

```
public class IconToImageSourceConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var icon = value as System.Drawing.Icon;
        var bitmap = icon.ToBitmap();

        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap/1069509#1069509
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        bitmap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
        ms.Position = 0;
        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
        bi.BeginInit();
        bi.StreamSource = ms;
        bi.EndInit();

        return bi;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The resource access modifier must be public
- If the image is added as "Image" you end up with a `Bitmap` instead of an Icon, which requires a different converter

Comment: Very useful... I think. I'm now getting an error that says:

Unknown build error, 'Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key Line 131 Position 34.'

Pointing to Binding Source="{x:Static res:AppResources.minimize}"

Comment: One thing that is important is that the resource access modifier is public as opposed to internal, but that throws another exception that the one you have.

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5 rather than 4.0 for backwards compatibility reasons - I don't suppose that could be an issue here?

Comment: Nope, i just went ahead and tested it in a new .NET 3.5 project, it worked.

Comment: Mmm, didn't think that'd be it. However, I'm also getting the strangest error now: _The type 'Helpers:IconToImageSourceConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built._ I've got the right `using` line in the code-behind, `xmlns:Helpers` is pointing to the correct namespace... What the hell?

Comment: Code behind does not matter, only the `xmlns` is important. Of course the class should be public too.

Comment: It is. When I type `Helpers:` VS gives me a dropdown with the other three classes in the Converters namespace, but doesn't seem to recognize IconToImageSourceConverter... I tried creating another converter class in case I somehow did something wrong the first time, same issue.

Comment: Still getting the "Key cannot be null" error as well, btw. Maybe they're somehow connected...

Comment: Found the error, finally! While modifying the code snippet you posted to match the style of my project, I changed `prop` to `res` in the code but neglected to fix `xmlns:prop` as well... My bad!