# display a System.Drawing.Bitmap object in a System.Windows.Controls.Image control

Tags: c#, wpf, image, xaml, bitmapimage

I have an image control as:

```
<Image Height="209" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="66,74,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" />
```

in a wpf application. I imported a library that converts a video to bitmap images and I am trying to place those bitmaps in the image countrol. There is a method that returns a System.Drawing.Bitmap object and I want to display that bitmap in image1. How could I do that?

Comment: You need to convert that bitmap to XAML compatible bitmap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert it to an `ImageSource` of some kind first. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap).

You can use a [`ValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to do this on the fly in the binding itself.