# Showing EXR/HDR in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, image, freeimage

How can I show EXR/HDR using FreeImage (Wrapper for .NET) as a WPF's Image?

And PNG, TIFF, TGA?

I'm trying and searching in the net, but I'm not able to show these images...

I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Thanks

Comment: I see there is already a wrapper for .NET in downloads section. So what you're searching for ?

Comment: I'm searching a way to put the exr image (loaded with the Wrapper) in a WPF Image

Comment: can you save it like Bitmap or get IO.Stream object from it?

Comment: Yes, I can save as Bitmap, but it become in a B&W bitmap. I'm using convertion to FIT_FLOAT and after to bitmap

Comment: So you want to be able to save it like color bitmap, or it's ok that its B&W?

Comment: I have to be able to show it in colors

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I assume you've been able to get a Bitmap instance successfully? If so, take a look at this post for converting it to a WPF image: [Load a WPF BitmapImage from a System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap)

If not, feel free to take a look at the source code for the FreeImageDecoder plugin at http://imageresizing.net/

Let me know and I'll update may answer accordingly.