# Bind Dynamically Created Bitmap object to Image in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a bitmap object that is not a static resource. Normally, with image binding in WPF you can bind to a string path. However, I have a dynamically created bitmap object that I would like to bind to. Is it possible to do something like:

```
<WrapPanel x:Name="imageWrapPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Image Source="{Binding Material1}" Margin="10" />
    <Image Source="/NightVision;component/Images/concrete_texture.tif" Margin="10" />
</WrapPanel>
```

And in the code behind file I have a public accessor:

```
public Bitmap Material1 { 
    get 
    { 
         return new Bitmap(/* assume created somewhere else*/) 
    } 
}
```

The above is obviously not working however, is there a way to do something similar?

Answer (score 5):

The only thing you need to do is convert the `Bitmap` to an `ImageSource` which can be used in the `Image` control. So in your binding you can add a [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) which accomplishes that. The implementation of the conversion is likely to be found in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap).

*(If you have a chance to work directly with `BitmapImage` (WPF) instead of `Bitmap` (WinForms) that might be quite a good idea)*