# Images from resource don't appear

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, resources, resx

I tried to load an image into my WPF project's main window. First I created RESX file called Images.resx (it's in Properties folder). Then I added an image called logo.png into this resource (using VS2010 RESX editor). Images were correctly copied into Resource folder. Then I changed Build Action property from Embedded Resource to Resource. After this I wanted to load my image in XAML.

```
<Image x:Name="image" Source="/MyProject;component/Resources/Logo.png" />
```

An image appeared in the preview in Expression Blend but when I compile the program, there is an empty window (without images).

Next I used ResourceDictionary. I created new file - Theme.xaml and added this:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="logo" UriSource="/MyProject;component/Resources/Logo.png" />
```

And in MainWindow.xaml:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/Theme.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<Image x:Name="image" Source="{StaticResource logo}" />
```

Again OK in Expression Blend but after compilation... Nothing appears:/

I tried to change back Build Action to Embedded Resource. Nothing happened.

Could anyone tell me how to use embedded resource from RESX file in XAML?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062221/images-bound-to-images-added-to-resx-files-using-xaml/8064281#8064281

Comment: Why do you add them to a resx in the first place? Do you localize them? If so, why then use absolute paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I found the answer... When I add some image into my RESX file, then it appears in Resource folder. Now I have to change Build Action of my RESX file AND IMAGES IN RESOURCES FOLDER