# WPF resx files in separate dll - can get string but can't get image

Tags: c#, wpf

**SOLVED**

Accepted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062221/images-bound-to-images-added-to-resx-files-using-xaml) did the trick (using converter)

---

I have resources.dll which contains not one, but multiple resource files like

- A.resx
- B.resx

Inside A.resx I have

- string TestString
- image TestImage

I'm referencing this dll in my project.

Inside xaml I have namespace declared

```
xmlns:res="clr-namespace:Resources;assembly=Resources"
```

and I'm trying to get content from resource A.resx.

This one works fine, I can get string from A.resx

```
<Label Content="{x:Static res:A.TestString}"/>
```

but I can't access image like this

```
<Image Source="{x:Static res:A.TestImage}" />
```

*The member TestImage is not recognised or accessible*

A.resx has

- access modifier set to public
- build action to Embedded Resource
- image persistence is set to Linked at compile time

If I can get string from it, but can't get image then **I have access** to resx file  and I can rule out permission/access problems. So there must be something that I'm doing wrong with this image.

Question is: why I can't get image from resx file and how to get this work?

Comment: *image persistence is set to `Linked` at compile time* - set `Embedded`.

Comment: Maybe you have to specify image *path* in full form `<Image Source="/Resources;component/A/TestImage"/>`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/347614/1997232). Can you use designer to generate path for you? Move cursor inside `<Image>`, hit Alt+Enter and open dropdown editbox for `Source`. Is there anything? If you click `TestImage` there, what will be generated in xaml?