# how to Convert byte to image and image to byte and display in image box in wpf c#

Tags: asp.net, wpf

my code for convert image to byte but i m getting black screen in image box:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(100, 100);
 MemoryStream MemImage = new MemoryStream();
 bitmap.Save(name, ImageFormat.Bmp);
 bitmap.Save(MemImage, ImageFormat.Bmp);
 byte[] Byte = MemImage.ToArray();
```

Convert byte to image :

```
byte[] data = (byte[])Query.Images;
MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();
strm.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
strm.Position = 0;
System.Drawing.Image imgTemp = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm);
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.BeginInit();
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
imgTemp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
bi.StreamSource = ms;
bi.EndInit();
ImageBox.Source = bi;
```

But in the above code one problem is image is not show in image box   (show black screen)
please solve this problem and send me.....Thanks

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/94456/1136211) for how to convert from Bitmap to BitmapImage.

Comment: try to bind that bytes to image source directly

Answer (score 3):

Try this code

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

Comment: Browse button: dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.ShowDialog();
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(dlg.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            data = new byte[fs.Length];

            fs.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
            fs.Close();

Comment: http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-save-and-retrieve-images-in-c-wpf-application-from-sql-server-database/