# How to load a bitmap to ImageSource real time in wpf?

Tags: wpf, bitmap, real-time, bitmapimage

I know how to convert bitmap into BitmapImage from [Load a WPF BitmapImage from a System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap)

But when my bitmap is changing, and I wanna the source of image, i.e. the BitmapImage will change with the bitmap in real time, how can I do it?

My code for generating bitmap is like this:

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300);
bitmap = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
DoWithGraphics(g, rect, pictureelements);
```

DoWithGraphics is a series of g.FillRectangle
Thanks!

Comment: Sooo.. you want to see each rectangle added to the image in real time?

Comment: DoWithGraphics will fill the rectangle and I want to see the rectangle real time. The project was implemented in WinForm originally and I'm trying to change it to WPF.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be a problem to display the bitmap in an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control and update the [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source.aspx) property whenever the bitmap changes.