# Fill WPF rectangle with Image

Tags: c#, wpf, xna

I created new WPF control, added a Rectangle to it, and everyhing works alright, its drawn like it should be. But I just cant paint the rectangle with an actual Image.

```
BitmapImage bi = GetImage();
ImageBrush imgBrush= new ImageBrush(bi);

this.rectangle.Fill = imgBrush;
```

But this code just makes the rectangle transparent, except the stroke.

This is the `GetImage()` method:

```
BitmapImage bi;

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;

    texture.SaveAsPng(ms, texture.Width, texture.Height);

    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    bi.BeginInit();
    bi.StreamSource = ms;
    bi.EndInit();

    ms.Close();
}
return bi;
```

`texture` is an `Texture2D` class, that is made before this code.

If I return `Bitmap` insted of `BitmapImage` here and then save that `Bitmap` the picture is drawn correctly.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Anyone has any idea why it doesnt work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way to convert `Bitmap to BitmapImage:`

```
using(MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Png);
    memory.Position = 0;
    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = memory;
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
}
```

Thanks to "Pawel Lesnikowski", he posted the anwser in the following topic:

[Load a WPF BitmapImage from a System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap)