# Why this line of code doesn't work?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I want to show an image from Disk !

```
private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(
        new Uri("images\\Countries\\dz.png",UriKind.Relative));
}
```

I'm sure that the filename is correct but
when I press the button, The image doesn't appear, I also made sure that the image is in the front of all other control and that `myImage` is its name .

Comment: Have you tried the absolute path in the uri, with a file:// prefix?

Comment: myImage is an Image control

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/94456/195488

But I don't think that is the one in the UI?

Comment: When you say 'nothing happens' it makes me think maybe the button isn't wired to the click event.

Comment: Attach the click event...? `Button.Click  += new EventHandler(this.Button_Click_3);`

Comment: do you already have a `Button.Click` event?  if you do, I'd just dispatch all the custom events from that.

Comment: Note that you specified a *relative* filename. Are you sure, the `images` directory is present in the applications working directory (which might be `bin\Debug` if you're running your app from within VisualStudio...)

Comment: Will you give a complete description of your code or give the complete code.

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the definition of myImage?

Comment: What container in the image element in?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(
        new Uri(@"images\Countries\dz.png",UriKind.Relative));
    }

    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

1. Putting @ makes it a literal string (you don't need to provide
   escape sequence then)
2. If the above also doesn't work then it'll show the exception if any
   occurs.

Comment: Putting `@` makes it a literal string, not a path.

Comment: Sorry yes it makes a literal string but you don't need to provide escape characters then

Answer (score 0):

Try to Debug it.
Put a break point on the line(F9) and hit F5 to start debugging. Check the value of `myImage.Source` after the line is executed (F10 to step).
You can also use the Immediate Window to test other statements while debugging is paused and see the results.

Also make sure that the images folder is in the same folder as the executable file (in Debug or Release folders, according to your build)

Answer (score 0):

```
BitmapImage bitImg = new BitmapImage();
bitImg.BeginInit();
bitImg.UriSource = new Uri("images\\Countries\\dz.png", UriKind.Relative);
bitImg.EndInit();

myImage.Source = bitImg;
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things that may help you:

Instead of:

```
myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images\\Countries\\dz.png",UriKind.Relative));
```

Try This:

```
BitmapImage ImageName = new BitmapImage;
ImageName.BeginInit();
ImageName.UriSource = new Uri(@"images\Countries\dz.png",UriKind.Relative);
ImageName.EndInit();
myImage.Source = ImageName;
```

See below link (examples section at the bottom of the page) for more info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx

If the above doesn't work, we will need you to post more code :). Also, it would help if you specify exactly what you are trying to achieve here.