# Paint images on PictureBox inside a UserControl WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms, picturebox

I'm trying to paint images on a `PictureBox` from a camera that I insert with a `WindowsFormsHost`. The code is as simple as follows:

```
<Window x:Class="videoTEst.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="583" Width="1132"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms">
<StackPanel Background="LightBlue" Height="513" Width="1077">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="450" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Name="ButtonOpen" Content="Load" Click="ButtonOpen_OnClick" />
        <Button Name="ButtonLoadImage" Content="Load image" Click="ButtonLoadImage_OnClick" />
        </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <WindowsFormsHost Name="WinFormsHost" Height="440" Width="690" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <wf:PictureBox x:Name="PictureBoxvideo" SizeMode="Normal" Paint="PictureBoxvideo_Paint"></wf:PictureBox>
        </WindowsFormsHost>
        <ListBox Name="ListBoxLog" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

And I paint from the camera like this:

```
 private void asyncVideoSource_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        Image temp = PictureBoxvideo.Image;
        Bitmap bitmap = eventArgs.Frame;
        PictureBoxvideo.Image = new Bitmap(bitmap);
        if (temp != null) temp.Dispose();
        bitmap.Dispose();
   }
```

This code works perfectly.

But when I change the `<Window>` tags to `<UserControl>` (as I want it to be embeded on my own `UserControl`), it doesn't paint!!

**Why isn't it painting on a `UserControl`?**

*Why I'm not using `Image` from WPF?* 
*`Image` has a threading use really confusing, and whenever I try to paint on the `Image`, the `Bitmap` was disposed before.*

Comment: There is nothing confusing about creating a WPF BitmapImage in another thread. Just call `Freeze` before using it in the UI thread. StackOverflow has a lot of answers that show how to do that, and of course also how to create a BitmapImage from a Bitmap.

Comment: @Clemens I tried to assign the Bitmap to an Image, but then it says that the process is in another thread. How can I paint the BitmapImage if I can't return to the main UI?
Could you provide a link to read about that? I didn't have knoweldege about what you say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of a PictureBox in a WindowsFormsHost you could simply use a WPF Image control:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Image x:Name="image" Height="440" Width="690" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    ...
</StackPanel>
```

You would now create a BitmapImage from the Bitmap object using code as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069509/1136211) or in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1069509/1136211), with an additional call to `Freeze` that makes it accessible in the UI thread:

```
Bitmap bitmap = eventArgs.Frame; // your NewFrameEventArgs
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = stream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
}

bitmapImage.Freeze();
```

Finally you would update the Image control in the UI thread by calling its Dispatcher:

```
image.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => image.Source = bitmapImage));
```