# C# Icon in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

My aim is to obtain the icons for installed programs and show these icons in WPF application.
My steps are as follow:

1. Get all the exe location, eg. C:\Windows\notepad.exe
2. Get the Icon object, using Icon anIcon = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(string)
3. Convert the icon to bitmap, using anIcon.ToBitmap()
4. insert bitmap in the application

But how should I do 4., the insertion?
In XAML, you have `<Image Source={xxx} />`. But the source is the location of the file. So how should I insert the bitmap into the XAML?

Comment: Do you have the Bitmap in code as a `BitmapSource` or something? You should be able to bind it via `{Binding MyImageProperty}` to your ViewModel (if you use MVVM) or the DataContext that you use. Where is your Bitmap currently located and how do the view know about it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94456/load-a-wpf-bitmapimage-from-a-system-drawing-bitmap

Comment: I generate the Bitmap object in step 3. So, please let me ask the question even more directly. Now I am in step 3. How should I proceed to insert this bitmap in WPF app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create the ImageSource from the Icon.

```
System.Windows.Media.ImageSource iconSource;
using (System.Drawing.Icon sysicon = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(FilePath))
{
    iconSource = System.Windows.Interop.Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
    sysicon.Handle,
    System.Windows.Int32Rect.Empty,
    System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}
return iconSource;
```

Sample Program - [Get Icon From FileName in WPF](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/get-icon-from-filename-in-wpf/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FileStream` and `BitmapImage` to achieve this.

```
using(FileStream Fs = new FileStream("path",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read))
{

    BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = Fs;
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();

    image.source = bitmapImage;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I use this approach, how can I position the icon? In fact I have several of them.

Comment: There is an Image control you can use in xaml. You can use the designer to set the image wherever you want.