# c# wpf assign bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, image, picturebox

I used to work with WFA but no I want to try the WPF platform, too.

I need to assign an existing bitmap to the image control.

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap sc = screenshot();
    ima.Source = new Bitmap(sc);
 }
```

this line just not working: `ima.Source = new Bitmap(sc);`

in picturebox it i can only use this

```
ima.Image = new Bitmap(sc);
```

but now its throwing an error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'.

Comment: have you solved it ?

Comment: @AbinMathew no... i really need to..

Comment: i just added another method to convert please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will convert the path to ImageSource.

```
<Image>
    <Image.Source>
         <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImagePath}" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

try in this way.

```
public ImageSource imageSourceForImageControl
{
  get
   {
     ImageSourceConverter c = new ImageSourceConverter();
     return (ImageSource)c.ConvertFrom(yourBitmap);
   }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesourceconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: allright what i do need to do now in order to assign the Imagepath in the c#?

Comment: Create a property in C#/VB called ImagePath, then assign the path to that property. eg: 
VB
Public Property ImagePath() As String
            Get
                Return _ImagePath
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                _ImagePath = value
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ImagePath")
            End Set
        End Property

Comment: but i dont have here the source.. im just generation an new bitmap using `screenshot` method. it returns a screen shot. its not an local image on the computer or somthing,

Comment: if that is the case you can take the answer given by "Schwarzbrot" and set the bitmapImage to the xaml.

Comment: its slow as hell bro...

Comment: how about saving screen shot and take the path ?

Comment: no no no i use it for screen sharing program

Comment: Am happy that it worked for you.

Comment: it didnt but thanks. i just using `windowsformshost` and added a picturebox to my wpf project... best solution trust me :P

Comment: .Net framework 4.5 and above, if you are using then it works for ImageSourceConverter

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the Search function:
[Convert System.Drawing.Bitmap to BitmapImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22499407/how-to-display-a-bitmap-in-a-wpf-image)

```
private BitmapImage BitmapToImageSource(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        Image i = new Image();

        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            memory.Position = 0;
            BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapimage.BeginInit();
            bitmapimage.StreamSource = memory;
            bitmapimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmapimage.EndInit();

            i.Source = bitmapimage;

            return bitmapimage;
        }
    }
```