# How to share pixel data between Bitmap and Bitmapsource without a reallocation?

Tags: c#, .net, image, bitmap, bitmapsource

Is it possible to create a `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Bitmapsource` from a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` without a reallocation?
Unfortunately all methods described in other post included a copy of the `pixel data` which is not always needed and very expensive...

Comment: As far as I can tell the only way is to create a `MemoryStream`, saving the bitmap to the stream and getting ImageSource from that stream. I never found any other way to do so. I have seen people using some extra libraries but I think those are based on the same principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32841840/5599927) and it worked perfectly for me!

```
WpfImage.Source = new SharedBitmapSource(DrawingBitmap);
```