# Why cant I assign Bitmap to Image.Source?

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, aforge

```
void VideoCaptureDevice_NewFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            pictureBox1.Source = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
        }
```

on Windows Form this works
pictureBox1.Image= (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
//But on Windows WPF-App not..

i found a Classs called IMAGE in System.Windows.Forms

```
pictureBox1.Image= (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
```

and this Code line is full functional in Windows Forms

But in Windows WPF-APP it wont, first I tryed to change the .Image to .Source

But now it says "implizit Bitmap into pictureBox.Source cant be converted"

Comment: You can not assign a WinForms Bitmap to the Source property of a WPF Image element. These are two different frameworks with different bitmap classes. The type of the Source property is ImageSource and you would typically use the derived types BitmapImage or BitmapFrame to assign a value. Take a look at the documentation.

Comment: For the conversion from Bitmap to BitmapImage see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/94456/1136211